# Why does my ResponseEntityExceptionHandler never get invoked?

Tags: validation, spring-boot, spring-4

I've got a simple `@RestController`. My ultimate goal is to be able to validate if an incoming `@QueryParam String id` is an `UUID`. That part works, but the exception being thrown by the `IsValidUUIDValidator` never goes through my custom `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`. I need that to be able to control the output of the errors.

I've read and tried out a range of tutorials and blogs, but no matter what I do validation exceptions never enter `GlobalExceptionHandler#handleMethodArgumentNotValid`.

Why are validation exceptions never run through `handleMethodArgumentValid` in my custom `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`?

*Note! I do see that Spring picks up the GlobalExceptionHandler from a simple log event in the default constructor of that class.*

**SearchResource**

```
@RestController
@Path("/search")
public class SearchResource extends AbstractResource {

    @GET
    @Path("/suggestions")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public Response getSuggestions(@IsValidUUID @QueryParam("territoryId") String territoryId) {
```

**IsValidUUID**

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = {IsValidUUIDValidator.class})
public @interface IsValidUUID {

    String message() default "Invalid UUID";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

}
```

**isValidUUIDValidator**

```
public class IsValidUUIDValidator implements ConstraintValidator<IsValidUUID, String> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(IsValidUUID constraintAnnotation) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if (value == null) {
            return false;
        }

        try {
            UUID.fromString(value);
            return true;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid!");
            context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
            context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("The provided UUID is not valid")
                    .addConstraintViolation();

            return false;
        }

    }

}
```

**GlobalExceptionHandler**

```
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        System.out.println("This method never gets invoked");
        return super.handleMethodArgumentNotValid(ex, headers, status, request); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

}
```

Comment: try adding `@ExceptionHandler( MethodArgumentNotValidException .class)`  in `GlobalExceptionHandler`  below `@Override` and if it doesn't work may be try changing `handleMethodArgumentNotValid` from `protected` to `public`

Comment: @rdj7 tried changing from `protected` to `public`, but no success. Adding `@ExceptionHandler` makes Spring complain about two exception handlers for `MethodArgumentNotValidException` since `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` already has an `@ExceptionHandler` for this exception in `handleException`.

Answer (score 1):

`ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` is a Spring MVC concept and only applies to Spring Controllers. From the look of it, your application is using Jersey. This won't apply here. You need to use the appropriate infrastructure for that in Jersey.